# Should I stop moving out of the house during the rainy season and enjoy the weather because there is high chance i can accidently kill insects?

Tags: sin

Should I stop moving out of the house during the rainy season and enjoy the weather because it may accidentally kill insects?

Is it a sin because consciously, I know there is a high chance of killing insects?

I want to enjoy weather and Play around but these thoughts keep coming to mind that you are hurting others in the activity. By not enjoying rain, you are avoiding sin of killing insects but isn’t this self extortion by not enjoying nature / rain. Isnt this self suppression?

Comment: During monsoon, movements must be restricted as far as possible. But, altogether can't be ceased. For example untill a farmer plough the field or work on farms in rains could we have food? Now coming for fun thing. Shastras usually prohibit anything for fun or pleasure which might hurt a jeeva. Moreover you can surely enjoy rains on roof tops or any similar structures. Mumbai generally has concrete structures so that's not a big deal for u. This is the reason u knw, it is advised to do Jalkrida (water sports) in natural water sources too, because the water organisms might be harmed in course.